# String Date to Milliseconds Android

Tags: android

I have value String "2016-02-27T00:49:18.5594825+11:00" , I want to convert to format Milliseconds. But I its not work. this may code:

```
public static long converStringtoMS(String d) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM.dd.yyyy");
    long a = 0;
    try {
        Date date = sdf.parse(d);
        a=date.getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return a;
}
```

But this is always 0, SO How to the right code?

Comment: This should be    `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM.dd.yyyy HH:mm:ss");`

Comment: isn't it "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss_SSS" ?

Comment: still not work sir :(